# creating a carousel with javascript?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, carousel

I want to create a carousel where if the user press prev and next only the image and its associated text should be displayed. Like for first item that is Image1, This is Image1 text should be displayed then if the user presses next Image2 and This is Image2 should be displayed.

Below is my code

Thanks

```
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    #container p{ display: inline; } 
  </style> 
  <script type="text/javascript" src="prototype.js" > </script> 
</head> 
<body> 
  <div id="container">
    <div id="section1">
      <img src="images/image1.jpg" height="20" width="20" />
      <p> This is a image1 </p>
    </div>
    <div id="section2">
      <img src="images/image1.jpg" height="20" width="20" />
      <p> This is a image2 </p>     
    </div>
    <div id="section3">
      <img src="images/image1.jpg" height="20" width="20" />
      <p> This is a image3 </p>
    </div>
    <a id="prev" href="#">Prev</a>
    <a id="next" href="#">Next</a>
  </div>


  <script type="text/javascript">
    Event.observe('prev', 'click', function(event){
      alert(' Prev clicked!');
    });

    Event.observe('next', 'click', function(event){ 
      alert(' Next clicked!');
    });

    $('section1').hide();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Doug,

did u edit it?

Answer (score 0):

http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/

@Nishant: you can place any text you want within the jcarousel elements, view the source of this example for instance:

http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/special_easing.html

Comment: how can i do that with text and image?

Comment: -1 This question was specifically tagged with Prototype, not jQuery

Comment: @Justin: you must've missed that it's *also tagged* javascript. jQuery and prototype can be *used together* without any problem.

Comment: No, no I didn't. Two libraries < one library

Comment: no, re-using libraries is *better* than re-inventing the wheel (or the carousel in this case). jcarousel provides effects, auto-scrolling, animation, etc. which can be turned on by setting an option.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple approach that gets the job done with a minor change to the HTML

JavaScript

```
Event.observe(window, 'load', function() {
    var current  = 0,
        sections = $$('.section'),
        len      = sections.length;

    var clear = function() {
        sections.each(function(s) { s.hide(); });
    };

    Event.observe('prev', 'click', function(event){
        // No wrapping
        // current = Math.max(0, current - 1);

        // Wrapping
        current = (current - 1 < 0) ? (len - 1) : (current - 1);

        clear();
        sections[current].show();
    });

    Event.observe('next', 'click', function(event){
        // No wrapping
        // current = Math.min(len -1, current + 1);

        // Wrapping
        current = (current + 1 == len) ? 0 : (current + 1);

        clear(); 
        sections[current].show();
    });

    clear();
    sections[current].show();
});
```

HTML

```
  <div id="container">
    <div class="section" id="section1">
      <img src="images/image1.jpg" height="20" width="20" />
      <p> This is a image1 </p>
    </div>
    <div class="section" id="section2">
      <img src="images/image1.jpg" height="20" width="20" />
      <p> This is a image2 </p>     
    </div>
    <div class="section" id="section3">
      <img src="images/image1.jpg" height="20" width="20" />
      <p> This is a image3 </p>
    </div>
    <a id="prev" href="#">Prev</a>
    <a id="next" href="#">Next</a>
  </div>
```

You didn't specify whether or not you wanted to have the carousel wrap around to the opposite end once it reached the first or last pane, so I gave you the math for both.

Comment: Thanks, you're right. I changed his markup but forgot to copy it over from my text page.  It's both easier to code and to maintain to simply add a unifying CSS class to the elements that are part of the carousel's content. It's also highly likely to be useful from a CSS perspective if the OP wants the different sections of the carousel to be uniform in size, position, etc.